# Proving that the category of forests $\mathcal{F}$ is isomorphic to $\text {Set} ^{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

I just started studying category theory. So far I learned the basic definitions of Categories, Functors, Natural transformations, and saw some examples. I want to show that the category of forests $\mathcal{F}$ is isomorphic to $\text{Set} ^{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$, with $\mathcal{C}$ a small category.

The definition that I'm using of forest is the following:

> A *forest* is a poset $(T,<)$ such that $\forall x\in T, T_x:=\{ y\in T \vert y<x \}$ is a finite totally ordered set.

**My attempt:**

[I made two silly mistakes below, pointed out in the comments - lost track of what $H(T)$ was and was thinking wrongly about forests. After realizing this with the help of the comments, the question vanished]

I want to find functors $H:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \text{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$ and $G:\text{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{op}}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ such that their compositions $GF$ and $FG$ are identities. 
In particular, I want $H(T)$ to be a functor $\mathcal{C}^{op}\rightarrow \text{Set}$. Take $\mathcal{C}=\mathbb{N}$ (viewed as a poset with the usual order), which is small. Also, suppose $T$ is countable. To construct $H(T)$ we do the following: we number the elements of $T$ by level of the forest, as illustrated in the picture.
[image]

Now, call $R\subseteq T\times T$ the order in $T$. For each pair in $R$, extract the corresponding pair of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$. The set of all such pairs is $H(T)$. In the example of the picture, $H(T) = \{ (0,2),(0,3),(0,5),(2,5),(3,5),(1,3),(1,4),(1,6),(4,6) \}$

$G$ is now defined as reversing this process. This gives us a problem as described below.

We still have to define how $H$ and $G$ act on arrows. Given a forest morphism $f:T\rightarrow T'$ (which preserves order and levels of a forest), we assign a map $H(f)$ between the sets $H(T)$ and $H(T')$ that assigns to each pair $(n(a),n(b))\in H(T)$ the pair $(n(f(a)), n(f(b)))$ where $n$ is the map assigning natural numbers to elements of a forest as (partially) described above. Again, $G$ is very naturally defined as reversing this.

**Problems:**

1. $G$ should take a set of pairs of natural numbers and give us a forest. But there is an ambiguity when constructing the forest: how to construct it in a way that reverses what $F$ does? *e.g.* when $F$ acts as described above, it may assign the number $4$ to an element to which $G$ assigned the number $3$, if these are in the same level of the forest (as in the picture above, for example). This problem can be restated as follows: my function $n$ above was not well defined, because I don't know how to assign numbers to the elements of a forest in a unique way.
2. I had to assume that $T$ was countable, which seems to be false in general. So maybe I could try to do the same but using $\mathbb{R}$ intead of $\mathbb{N}$, but I am not sure exactly how to do it rigorously.

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Why do you think this is possible at all? You apply an inconsistent understanding of what a functor is. You correctly note that $H(T)$ needs to be a functor $\mathcal C^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$, but then immediately after illustrating that a functor needs to map objects to objects (among other things), you say $H(T)$ is a set. It's not clear how $\mathcal C=\mathbb N$ even factors in to your example of $H(T)$. If $H(T):\mathbb N^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$, then, among other things, $H(T)$ is a mapping from objects of $\mathbb N$ to sets, i.e. you need to provide a set $H(T)(n)$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Specifically, an object, $F$, of $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbb N^{op}}$ is, as you say, a functor $F:\mathbb N^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$. This is an infinite sequence of sets, $F(n)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$, and an infinite sequences of functions $f_n : F(n+1)\to F(n)$, and that's it. There are no additional constraints on these sets or functions. (In regards to the previous comment, I'm not saying it is impossible to do what you want, but I'm wondering what makes you believe it is possible.)

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but your picture doesn't look like it depicts a forest.

Comment: @Hurkyl You are right. After realizing the two simple, dumb mistakes I was making (pointing out by you and Derek), it was simple to find a solution. I wonder if I should delete this question, since it is only going to be useful to someone who made exactly the same silly mistakes as I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $\mathcal C$ to be the set of non-negative integers considered
as an ordered set?

The image of $0$ is the set of roots, and the map $n\mapsto {n-1}$
induces the map of nodes of distance $n$ from the root to their parents.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "the map of nodes of distance $n$ from the root to their parents." Could you please clarify?

Comment: I think, a correct version of that sentence is that 'the arrow $(n-1)\to n$ of $\mathcal C$ induces the <parent> map on the nodes of level $n$'.